# Ensure every function in an interface passed as a generic is asynchronous

Tags: typescript

suppose I have an abstract class which takes a generic

```
export abstract class RegisterableClass<InstanceType>
```

and an implementer below as such:

```
class UserService extends RegisterableClass<IUserService> implements IUserService {
  someConstant: 42,
  async getAllUsers: (): User[] => {...}
}
```

with an interface like:

```
interface IUserService {
  someConstant: number;
  getAllUsers: () => Promise<User[]>;
}
```

I want to ensure that the passed generic, `IUserService`, in this particular case, are *all* asynchronous.

Can I do this statically with TypeScript somehow?

maybe using `Extract<keyof IUserService, Function>` ? and then passing that to something in turn?

That is, if you attempt to `extend RegisterableClass` and pass it a generic in which not all functions are async, typescript will not compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you'd like to [constrain the type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) passed to `RegisterableClass` to be something whose methods are all asynchronous (meaning that they return promises).

If so, you can achieve that like this:

```
type AllMethodsAreAsync<I> = {
    [K in keyof I]: I[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ?
    R extends Promise<any> ? I[K] : (...args: any) => Promise<R> :
    I[K]
}

export abstract class RegisterableClass<I extends AllMethodsAreAsync<I>> {
    // ... something involving I, hopefully
}
```

The type function `AllMethodsAreAsync<I>` will be equivalent to `I` if `I` is an object type whose function-valued properties return promises.  But if `I` has any function-valued properties that don't return promises, the corresponding property of `AllMethodsAreAsync<I>` will be changed to return a promise instead.

Then, if `I extends AllMethodsAreAsync<I>` passes the generic constraint, great.  Otherwise, you should get an error telling you exactly what from `I` doesn't work.  Like this:

```
// adding this so standalone example works
type User = { u: string }; 

interface IOkayService {
    someConstant: number;
    getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]>;
}

type OkayService = RegisterableClass<IOkayService>; // okay

interface IBadService {
    someConstant: number;
    getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]>;
    getSomethingSynchronously(x: string): number;
}

type BadService = RegisterableClass<IBadService>; // error!
//                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'IBadService' does not satisfy the constraint 'AllMethodsAreAsync<IBadService>'.
// Types of property 'getSomethingSynchronously' are incompatible.
// Type '(x: string) => number' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => Promise<number>'.
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number>'.
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-H7ez0cACrWqAAci3iZ3Qs-UCYOgED+N2DTYAYwDhOIIBQGg0BkJKrQGMyX6LMgaBYLgBBEO21Dbgue6froL5QO+kD+BIUBgMEkD1LBn5Fo24rNq27adgiPZ9iAAFGNAAiIaikF8J6JGAuR0CfoOw40i2mR0OOjgAeCYHpL0fDGCQHrosAkIzl+yS6EYpjmJY8kVrkhqKXgNDEaRElftZymgegDQbhpWmenBekfp++p5BQ1m2SRVQsEAA)

Does that do what you want?  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: You are a TypeScript god! I tried using a type but was getting the error about not being able to statically analyze types in the manner I was doing it. Exactly what I want. Well done.

Comment: I have a follow up, maybe a bit interesting.

I would like to type the constructor function of `RegisterableClass`. That is `type RegisterableClassConstructor<I> = new() => RegisterableClass<I>`. However, an error is thrown:

`Type 'I' does not satisfy the constraint 'AllMethodsAreAsync <I>'`

Comment: `type RegisterableClassContructor<I extends AllMethodsAreAsync<I>> = new() => RegisterableClass<I>` ?

Comment: I see, because if something extends another interface it must all conform to it. Still pretty new to typed languages, thanks once more.